# AWK - How to do the sorting?

Tags: sorting, awk, multiple-columns

In awk, how can I do this:

```
1303361997;15;67.067014
1303361997;5;51.529837
1303361997;14;47.036197
1303361997;3;44.064681
1303361997;6;37.632831
1303361997;23;24.990078
1303361997;24;26.750984
1303361998;15;67.074100
1303361998;5;51.522981
1303361998;14;47.028185
1303361998;3;44.056715
1303361998;6;37.638584
1303361998;23;24.987800
1303361998;24;26.756648
```

When number in second columns is absent this date should be replace by zero in output file.
First place is the number of the first column. The values ​​of the second column of data to determine the position of the third column in the output file. The first column each time it may begin with different values. Desired output, by sorting first and second columns:

```
1303361997;0;0;44.064681;0;51.529837;37.632831;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;47.036197;67.067014;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;24.990078;26.750984;
1303361998;0;0;44.056715;0;51.522981;37.638584;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;47.028185;67.074100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;24.987800;26.756648;
```

Comment: I fixed code to exclude ambiguity of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=";" }
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        min[i] = max[i] = $i
    }
}
{
    val[$1,$2] = $3
    keys[$1]
    for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        min[i] = ($i < min[i] ? $i : min[i])
        max[i] = ($i > max[i] ? $i : max[i])
    }
}
END {
    for (r=min[1];r<=max[1];r++) {
        if (r in keys) {
            printf "%d",r
            for (c=1;c<=max[2];c++) {
                printf ";%s", ((r,c) in val ? val[r,c] : 0)
            }
            print ";"
        }
    }
}
$
$ cat file
1303361997;15;67.067014
1303361997;5;51.529837
1303361997;14;47.036197
1303361997;3;44.064681
1303361997;6;37.632831
1303361997;23;24.990078
1303361997;24;26.750984
1303361998;15;67.074100
1303361998;5;51.522981
1303361998;14;47.028185
1303361998;3;44.056715
1303361998;6;37.638584
1303361998;23;24.987800
1303361998;24;26.756648
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1303361997;0;0;44.064681;0;51.529837;37.632831;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;47.036197;67.067014;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;24.990078;26.750984;
1303361998;0;0;44.056715;0;51.522981;37.638584;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;47.028185;67.074100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;24.987800;26.756648;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After editing, I saw that the corrected version of the code is not shown. The entry window has decided to play tricks on me. In any case, present the correct version. I understand that correctly process the correct data, I need to read the value of the first column and substitute this value in the loop?

Comment: @diletant I updated my answer to produce your new expected output from your new sample input.

Comment: @Morton
Thank you once again. I did not wait and made a little differently. The first value in the first column is always the minimum, then we can use it for the initial value of the loop. The advantage is that there is no need for finding the minimum value.
`BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=";";} 
{
    val[$1,$2] = $3;
    for (i=1;i<=2;i++){
      max[i] = ($i > max[i] ? $i : max[i]);
      if (NR==1) start=$1;
    }
}
END { 
     for (r=start;r<=max[1];r++) {
       printf "%d",r
       for (c=1;c<=max[2];c++){
         printf ";%g", val[r,c]
       }
       print ""
    }
}`